# Mongo Replica internal SSL issue

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, ssl, replicaset

I have setup mongo replica set in Amazons AWS. It has one Primary and two secondary instances.I want SSL secure connection between mongo instances(pri to sec or sec to pri).

I have config mongo to use SSL by adding below settings in **mongod.conf**

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
  ssl:
    mode: requireSSL
    PEMKeyFile: /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem
    PEMKeyPassword: password
    clusterFile: /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem
    clusterPassword: password
    weakCertificateValidation: false
    allowInvalidCertificates:  false
```

After restarting mongo, replicas are communicating but I am not sure is connection between them is secured by SSL or not.

How I can check connection between primary and secondary are secure or not?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [packet sniffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer) to check the actual data being sent and received; that would show whether it is going out plain or encrypted.